# Sort the value of a column with a relative position (using an other column data order)

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a form to collect data from user A in a sheet and reformat it for user B in the other sheet.

I have to sort the data for user B. I'm using `vlookup` to sort the column of values from the form to a new sheet (sort based on the order of the 'value description column'). It's working.

My problem is that when a new column is added to the first sheet (the form) the column range is modified and the index parameter in `vlookup` is not good anymore. So I lost everything on my second sheet.

How can I do to have a solid link with the column in the first sheet even if it's position change?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `INDIRECT` with `COUNTA` and `SUBSTITUTE`. something like:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1), 4), 1, "")
```

this will count non-empty cells in row `1` of `Sheet1` and converts that number to later which is used in constructing the range put together by `indirect` formula and all of it can be placed in `vlookup` as same as you would place any ther regular range.